# Replace substring of given indices range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python programming. I am stuck at one point. Let's say I have string "hello-world". I want to replace all the characters of this string with "*" except first & last. so the result will be `"h***-****d"`.

One way to do this as below:

```
In [1]: s = "hello-world"

In [2]: s[0] + "*"*(len(s)-2) + s[-1]
Out[2]: 'h*********d'
```

If I want to replace all characters with "*" except first & last 2 characters

```
In [3]: s[:2] + "*"*(len(s)-4) + s[-2:]
Out[3]: 'he*******ld'
```

Is there any pretty way to handle these type of problems. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That's about as pretty as it's going to get

Comment: Seems like your code works and you understand the logic- you just need to turn it into a function.

Comment: "Pretty" is a subjective term. Your code works, and it's reasonably performant. Embed it in a method with a reasonable name and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is your expected output `h****-****d` or `h*********d`? (The first one leaves the hyphen as it is)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to not repeat yourself:

```
def replace(s, n):
    if len(s) > n*2:
        return s[:n] + '*'*(len(s)-n*2) + s[-n:]
    return s

print(replace('hello-world', 1))  # h*********d
print(replace('hello-world', 2))  # he*******ld
print(replace('hello', 2))  # he*lo
print(replace('hello', 3))  # hello
```

You can also use some kind of string formatting instead of concatenation (which should be more efficient), e.g. [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) available in 3.6+:

```
def replace(s, n):
    if len(s) > n*2:
        return f"{ s[:n] }{ '*'*(len(s)-n*2) }{ s[-n:] }"
    return s
```

Comment: There's a few things worth negging for here:  1. the slicing can corrupt data (for example `s='hello'`, `n=3`), the code from [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52409668/674039) answer gives a better result there.  2. binding a lambda to a name is dumb, just use a `def`.  3. on a stylistic note, this is too much logic to cram into an f-string.

Comment: 1. fixed. 2. binding a lambda to a name is totally fine if a function just evaluates an expression. Even Raymond Hettinger [does](https://pybay.com/site_media/slides/raymond2018-keynote/doctest.html) it ;) 3. That's pretty subjective.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
def obscure(string, n):
    characters = list(string)
    characters[n:-n] = '*' * len(characters[n:-n])
    obscured = ''.join(characters)
    return obscured
```

Turn the string into a list of characters. Replace the ones you want to obscure. Then join the list back into a string.

Comment: You have the right idea, but you probably meant `list(string)` instead of `string.split()`, and you need the length of the `'*'` to match the length of what they're replacing in the slice assignment.

Comment: `characters[n:-n] = '*'` replaces the entire slice with a single `*`.

Comment: With what @JohnGordon  says, you'd need to replace it with `'*' * len(characters[n:-n])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` (and the `string` module to check against letters):

```
s[0] + ''.join(['*' if i in string.ascii_letters else i
                for i in s[1:-1]]) + s[-1]
```

Since you said you wanted `h****-****d` where the hyphen isn't replaced, you would need to test whether the characters are letters or not. You could change `string.ascii_letters` to:

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
chars = chars + chars.upper() + '0123456789'  # + 'some_other_chars'
```

...if you want to include other characters like numbers or punctuation. Or you can write out the letters you want to replace manually.

You may also want to perform a check to see whether the string is 3 characters or more so that no errors are raised.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this.

```
s="hello-world"

for i in s[1:-1]:
   if i.isalpha():
     s=s.replace(i,"*")
```

Comment: OK but what if the string is `"let’s test this`"?

Comment: Now, It will accept any string and replace every alphabet with "*" and "-" is not replaced.

Comment: Can you please check now @konrad Rudolph

Comment: `str.replace` doesn't do what you think it does. But even if it did this would be *really* inefficient for long strings, since it needs to copy the whole string for each character.

Comment: I will check more effective solution. Thanks @KonradRudolph